# Align flex item to end of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using flexbox, how can you align a `<p>` to its parent's "end"?

According to the documentation, adding `align-content: flex-end` to the parent element should be enough. However, this isn't working in the example below.

**Example:**

Here is a simple div containing a `p` element.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-end; /* This should do the alignment, but doesn't. */
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Align me to the end.</p>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkeuLb2b/)

A hacky solution would be to add a `::before` to the child with `flex: 1`, but I'm curious if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `align-content` property only works when there are multiple lines of flex items in a container. This property is designed to distribute the space between lines.

Since there is only one line in your container, `align-content` is having no effect.

Use `align-items` in a single line container.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;     /* changed from align-content */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* optional */
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Align me in the bottom left corner.
  </p>
</div>
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkeuLb2b/1/)

> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within
>   the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis,
>   similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the
>   main-axis.
>
> Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex container.
>
> Only multi-line flex containers ever have free space in the cross-axis
>   for lines to be aligned in, because in a single-line flex container
>   the sole line automatically stretches to fill the space.